# Does NLTK return different results on each run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

Does Python's NLTK toolkit return different results for each iteration of:

1) tokenization

2) POS tagging?

I am using NLTK to tag a large text file. The tokenized list of tuples has a different size every time. Why is this?

Comment: we would need an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither modify their logic or computation in any iterative loop.

In NLTK, tokenzation by default is rule based, using Regular Expressions, to split tokens from a sentence

POS tagging by default uses a trained model for English, and will therefore give the same POS tag per token for the given trained model. If that model is trained again, it will change.

Therefore the basic answer to your question is `no`

Answer (score 0):

Both the tagger and the tokenizer are deterministic. While it's possible that iterating over a Python dictionary would return results in a different order in each execution of the program, this will not affect tokenization -- and hence the number of tokens (tagged or not) should not vary. Something else is wrong with your code.